# Relating to design and runtime - is it better to parallelize smaller sub-tasks or bundled tasks?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, python, patterns-and-practices, architectural-patterns

I'm programming a small web scraper in python which I want to speed up by parallelizing things. The scraper is crawling URLs whereby a single URL can represent an 'item' or an 'index'. An index in this case is a list of URLs of other items and indexes. The parsing for an item URL differs from the parsing of an index URL.

So for every URL the following happens:

1. fetch source from URL
2. check if URL is index or item
3. parse source (depending on index or item)

I'm now thinking of two different solutions for parallelizing the process:

a)  use a queue of URLs, a worker process takes one URL and does 1 - 3 sequential

b) use a queue of tasks ( e.g. "fetch source"), a worker process does only 1, 2 or 3

I think a) is more logical and maybe better readable in the implementation. Also I don't know if one solution is faster then the other.

What would be the best way to realize my project?

Answer (score 1):

To increase parallelism, we want to look at several things: (i) subdividing the work, and (ii) latency issues.

To increase performance (assuming we now have parallelism) we want to (iii) look at how caches are used and (iv) avoid unnecessary operating system overheads associated with context switching (from having too many threads that are CPU bound, as not only does context switching have its own overhead, but also tends to cool the caches).

We subdivide the work (i) so that multiple CPUs can be applied, and, we identify high-latency operations so that we can use fewer overall threads.

---

In your sequential steps, significant network latency can exist between requesting the URL and receiving the document at that URL.

If we dedicate worker(s) to doing things involving latency, we'll have worker(s) often blocked just hanging around waiting for responses from the network.  We'll need to have plenty of workers because of that, and we're relying on the language & operating system efficiency of threading implementations for scale.

That's not to say this can't work, but an alternative using simple objects instead of threads would likely scale better.

---

The main point I'd make is that it seems that while your step (1) has latency, steps (2) & (3) do not appear to have latency, meaning they are likely both CPU bound operations.

So, I'd probably have two worker groups and a queue in front of each.  The first queue would hold URLs to visit, and have worker group as a simple background thread (e.g. maybe just one worker) to fire off the network requests essentially asynchronously.  One things this worker might do is impose any necessary throttling (e.g. total outstanding URL fetches, or URLs to same server, or monitor its output queue for being too large (meaning the second stage is getting behind)).

The second queue would be dedicated to received network results, and have workers handling those results as they come in doing (2) & (3) together.  You might want as many of these workers as you have CPUs; more will not help much and may even hurt.

In this approach, we're using smaller objects (than threads) to scale, and keeping the number of total threads closer to the number of CPUs.

---

Thus, I would not have separate worker groups for (2) and (3) connected with a queue in between, and instead I'd suggest just one worker group, where these workers sequentially processes (2) & (3).  I don't see any point to separating 2 & 3 (unless there is a huge cache benefit for running many 2's in a row and then many 3's in a row, though this doesn't jump out as likely for what you're describing).

If you did separate 2 & 3, you'd have to figure out how many of each to have, and here run the risk of thrashing the caches if you get into too much context switching.

Answer (score 1):

Techincally, it makes sense to seperate 1 from 2 and 3.

1 is bound by network throughput. while 2 and 3 are cpu limited. You dont want a bottle neck in one holding up the other.

Architecturally it makes more sense to split 1, 2, 3-item 3-index.

Since you have gone down the queue/worker/messages route, you might as well go the whole hog and embrace it. This gives you the added flexibility of being able to pull out and replace a single step without affecting the others.

Say for example you decide there is a 3rd category of page, index, item and stream. you could replace 2 with your new logic and add a new stream parser process without affecting 1 or 3

Or perhaps you decide that index processing is more important than item. You can scale up the number of workers for index and leave the item processing running at the slower rate.